# Is it normal to mushrooms caps to dry over a day?

Tags: mushrooms

Yesterday I was watering one small succulent plant I take care I noticed three Mushroom caps growing next to it. I took a photo and let them be. Today I woke up excitedly to check on them and found that they had opened their caps already, I added some more water and went to work.
However now that I'm back from work I noticed that they are drying and look like dying.

[image]
[image]
[image]

They looked like grooved bonnets on an app I'm using, but I'm not sure.

I was expecting that they would stand more than just 24h. Is this normal to this type of mushroom? They aren't anything fancy but I was quite delighted they were there.

**Edit:** I understand that the organism below the surface is probably alive, my question is focussed on the caps specifically

Answer (score 3):

24 hours seems quite quick, but likely they had been there for at least some hours before you noticed them. Mushrooms/toadstools are just the fruiting bodies of the mycelium in the soil; their purpose is to disseminate spores from the gills beneath the caps, and once they've done that,they degenerate quickly. Average time for mushrooms to be present is between about 3-7 days, depending on local conditions and the variety of mushroom.

Comment: Some caps liquefy as the mature like shaggy manes (  I think that is barristers wig in the UK).

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is definitely common, in fact inkcap mushrooms will turn into a black liquid overnight as they breakdown and spore. The mushrooms only purpose is to drop spores they are the sexual organs of the mycelium and once that happens they shrivel and die pretty promptly.